# Implementing react server side rendering and responsive components

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, server-side-rendering, react-boilerplate

I am using  [react-responsive-redux](https://github.com/modosc/react-responsive-redux) in which the whole Implementation of media queries is done based on a variable in state called [fakeWidth](https://github.com/modosc/react-responsive-redux/blob/master/lib/components.js) . To get it working according to the docs we need to [dispatch a redux action during request handler](https://github.com/modosc/react-responsive-redux#server-setup). In my project I do that in the [serverEntry.js](https://github.com/gitserverhu/ustraa_v2_react/blob/features/mobile-detect/v1.4/app/serverEntry.js) file, though the in built helper components of the module did not work because in my project I am using immutableJs.

So Now I am using [selectors.js](https://github.com/gitserverhu/ustraa_v2_react/blob/features/mobile-detect/v1.4/app/containers/App/selectors.js) to get the fakeWidth that is present in the state.

[This](https://github.com/gitserverhu/ustraa_v2_react/blob/features/mobile-detect/v1.4/app/containers/HomePage/index.js) works well but the component in the media query component (that says Mobile device) does not show up in the first render of the app. 
I am not able to figure out why is that happening and what should I do to prevent that.

[image: Mobile device is in MediaQuery component right now]

Comment: It would be a lot of work for an answerer to follow all your code links and review your full code base. You'll get better help if you break the problem down into a small sample app and post the actual code here.

Comment: Okay thanks for the suggestion, It will take me sometime to do that. I am gonna work on that and let this be here.